# Why PDO DELETE- query does'nt work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I try to delete records  from few tables with JOIN, but my pdo-query don't work and i not understand why ? . Please , tell me what am  i doing wrong

```
public function clear()
{

    try {

        $rows = $this->pdo->prepare("
                    DELETE p,ptc,pts,pd
                    FROM `product`  as p
                    LEFT JOIN `product_to_category` as ptc using(product_id)
                    LEFT JOIN `product_to_store` as pts using(product_id)
                    LEFT JOIN `product_description` as pd using(product_id)
                    WHERE p.isImport is true and ptc.category_id =1126
                    ");
        $rows->execute();

        if(file_exists(DIR_ADMIN.'added.txt'))
        {
            unlink(DIR_ADMIN.'added.txt');
        }

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: Alex, First of all what is the purpose of left join in this query. Also did you executed the SQL directly in mysql command prompt or phpmyadmin or mysql workbench and what error it throws. Also please add the detail regarding whether you enabled PDOException handling `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. Why don't you catch PDOException instead of generic Exception class.

Comment: I use LEFT  JOIN because  i delete many rows  from few tables , if i use old mysql_ function (mysql_connect,mysql_query)  ,statement  work , but in pdo this sql doesn't work

Comment: you have to ask your PHP for this, not us. does your PDO report its errors?

Comment: yeah , lol , problem solved, i use uncorrect  dsn on create connection to database